# RobotFramework: how to open testautomation on a specific PC screen?

Tags: robotframework

I'm using RobotFramework.

I use 'Browser' library and 'SeleniumLibrary' library.

I have 3 computer screens, let's call them 1 , 2 and 3

Now I'd like to open the testautomation on Screen #2

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Feature like this depends on the operating system and its specific desktop environment - nothing to do with robotframework itself or anything RF could solve.

Answer (score 0):

not entirly true,

stackoverflow.com/questions/66569867/how-to-choose-which-monitor-robot-framework-will-display-test-execution

then at the bottom it says python file
and from a python file a library can be made

almost there. but yes more convenient would be an inbuild argument to use for it.